# Getting images from S3 with a cookie to display on react

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, cookies, axios, amazon-cloudfront

I'm building an application with express backend and react frontend. The user can upload images and they're stored in a S3 bucket with a privacy policy and served through Cloudfront.

Currently, I'm using signed urls as a two step way to retrieve the images:

- React requests the Express server for a signed url for the image
- Express responds with the url
- React then loads the `<img src={signedUrl} />` tag.

This works, but I rather eliminate the signed url step and use something like cookies so the client can directly ask cloudfront for the image: `<img src={cfUrl + cookies?} />` I've tested this using postman and I can retrieve the image directly as long as I pass the cookies. So i know my cookies are setup correctly and the content is being served.

However, I'm not sure how i can do it on react with axios... The application is currently on localhost but It will be deployed to heroku.

**Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
  credentials: true,
}));

app.post('/cookies', async (req, res) => {
    // Function to generate the signed cookies
    const cookies = await awsS3.generateCookies();
    
    Object.entries(cookies).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      console.log(key, value);
      res.cookie(key, value);
    });
    res.json([]);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || config.port;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Express server is running on port: ${port}...`);
});
```

What i want to do in react:

```
<img src={image_url} />
```

However, looking at the network call for the image request, the cookies are not included by default. I don't know if i need to do something special or specific to include the cookies on that image request.

Comment: Have you checked the signed cookies for this?

Comment: Yes. I'm using signed cookies. Cloudfront is delivering the content as long as the cookies are passed on the request. 

The question is how can i have react pass the cookies on the `<img />` tag so the content can be retrieved

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by pass a cookie on IMG tag. Have a look at my answer and let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here is an overview of how CloudFront signed cookies work:

1. A user signs in to your website and either pays for content or meets some other requirement for access.
2. Your application returns the `Set-Cookie` headers in the response, and the viewer stores the name-value pairs.
3. The user requests a file e.g. an image in your case.
4. The user's browser or other viewer gets the name-value pairs from step 3 and adds them to the request in a Cookie header. This is the signed cookie.
5. CloudFront uses the public key to validate the signature in the signed cookie and to confirm that the cookie hasn't been tampered with. If the signature is invalid, the request is rejected.

More details can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html#private-content-how-signed-cookies-work).

**UPDATE**

Setting cookies for different domains is obviously not allowed. However, one can use a top level apex domain in a signed cookie, for example, `.example.com`. If properly set this cookie will always be sent to any request made to example.com, but also to any of its subdomains, e.g., `cloudfront.example.com`. So we can take advantage of this and have our backend service, which is running on `backend.example.com` create and set a signed cookie for `.example.com`. Later when the frontend requests a file form  `cloudfront.example.com` it will automatically include the signed cookie with the request.

This approach requires having a custom domain for a Cloud Front distribution. Here [docs how to do that](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html)

Best, Stefan

Comment: Thank you Stefan, i think i'm missing something here... When i check my network tab, the image request is not including the cookies. 

I've updated the original question to include my code to sign the cookies. Maybe that clarifies a bit both my issue and the potential solution?

Comment: I think you need to use `Set-Cookies` HTTP response header. See step 2 in my answer. Then the browser should send them automatically, when making a request

Comment: The cookies are making it to the client. (the toy server above should prove it). I can see the cookies on the browser, so I know they're getting passed down.

The problem is the browser not attaching them to the image request to cloudfront when making that request.

Comment: I don't really see where you use set-cookies header? That is the **only** correct way to send cookies to the client

Comment: Hi Stefan, `res.cookie(key, value);` is the bit that sets the cookie. It's the way express does it. 


However, i think i found the issue: The domain set by express is `locahost` so the cookie is not forwarded to cloudfront. 


I need to find a way to make sure my domains match so the cookie get properly forwarded to cloudfront.

Comment: @roloenusa Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @roloenusa were you able to solve the problem with my answer?

Comment: I was not. Basically the cookie has to be assigned a *.cloudfront.net domain, which i cannot do from my server (setting the domain is just not allowed). 

That means cookies are never forwarded to cloudfront on the image request.